# Hit Test rotated view

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, cgpoint

I need to write a `function` that will return `true` if given `point` is inside any of `subviews hierarchy` of `view A`. `A` can be `transformed` (rotated), and has `clipToBounds` disabled. It's subviews also can have `clipToBounds` disabled, and `true` must returned if any of `subviews` is tapped. I have something that almost works, but fails when view is rotated. Can someone suggest how to fix this?

```
extension UIView {

    func hitTestIgnoringBounds(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool {

        guard !isHidden && alpha > 0 else { return false }

        let subPoint = frame.origin - point
        return frame.contains(point) || subviews.contains {
            return $0.hitTestIgnoringBounds(subPoint)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How could I get position if point in coordinate space of this view? I mean if I have a view added above this view in hierarchy, and then move it inside that rotated view, at what position it would be to look like it didn't moved (in terms of point, not frame). I tried use let pointInCurrentCoordinateSpace = convert(point, from: superview), but this return the same point as given in input.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it should have been easy, but could not make it work. I made a stupid mistake - my code was adding sublayers instead of subviews. When I switched to subviews, everything worked fine:

```
func viewOrSubviewsContaintPoint(_ point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    let convertedPoint = convert(point, from: superview)
    let containsPoint = bounds.contains(convertedPoint)

    var subviewsContainsPoint: Bool {
        return subviews.contains { $0.viewOrSubviewsContaintPoint(convertedPoint) }
    }

    return containsPoint || subviewsContainsPoint
}
```